# Which processor instructions are used most commonly?

Tags: x86, profiling, instruction-set, usage-statistics, quantitative

My objective is to do comparative study of a few instruction set architectures.
For each instruction set architecture, how can i find the most commonly used instructions?

This is the steps i am thinking of:

- Find common ISAs for a chosen domain
- Find popular programs for each such ISA
- Disassemble the program instructions (.code) (which tool?)
- Collect statistics on instruction format, opcode, type. (which tool?)

Here is a very good study on x86 machine code statistics:
https://www.strchr.com/x86_machine_code_statistics

I have tried below command for disassembling, but it does not seem to disassemble properly. Disassembled code shows some `das` instructions, which should not be present in actual code.

```
ndisasm -b32 -a $(which which)
```

Comment: A disassembler does not know whether something is data or code. They may even be the same – data can be treated as code, code as data (the von Neumann architecture as implemented in all current CPUs). That is why you cannot point a generic disassembler to a random piece of an executable and say, "disassemble this!" You *can* but, as you found, it *will* disassemble whatever you are pointing it to.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, but thankfully `objdump` recognizes ELF file. `objdump --disassemble $(which ls) > ls.log` seems to do the right disassembly.

Comment: You cannot be 100% sure about that; there may still be static data – and even unused code! – inside executable sections.

Comment: Then i guess, an appropriate way to know the instructions being used would be to run it on a debugger, and somehow let it print out the executed instructions to a file. What do you think?

Comment: @wolfram77: I think there's a major difference between "generated by a compiler most often" and "executed by a CPU most often"; and you'll need to figure out which is better for your purposes.

Comment: @usr2564301: Plain non-obfuscated compiler-generated x86 executables do disassemble easily.  x86 compilers don't mix code and data; unlike ARM there's no benefit to literal pools near code (between functions) so compilers don't do it.  Of course you have to use a disassembler like `objdump` or `objconv` that knows about ELF metadata, which `ndisasm` does not!  ndisasm treats everything as a flat binary, including metadata and .data and .rodata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this, to gather mnemonics from .text section:

```
objdump --no-show-raw-insn \
        -M intel           \
        -sDj .text $(which *program name*) | # <-- disassemble .text section
             sed -n '/<\.text>/, $ p'      | # <-- skip raw hex
             awk '{$1 = ""; print}'        | # <-- remove offsets
             sed '1d'                        # <-- delete annoying <.text> in first line
```

After that you can either get only mnemonics name, appending `awk '{print $1}'`
to previous command, or mutating data somehow different.

After all of this add `sort | uniq -c` to previous steps.
So my resulting command looked like:

```
objdump --no-show-raw-insn \
        -M intel           \
        -sDj .text $(which *program name*) | 
             sed -n '/<\.text>/, $ p'      | 
             awk '{$1 = ""; print}'        |
             sed '1d'                      |
             awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

Which prints out frequencies of every mnemonic from program's text section

Comment: Thanks for posting a nice solution. I removed the first `sed` otherwise i dont get anything. Also content of `.text` is not necessary so `-s` is not needed too. Now i do get a listing of instructions with their counts (along with some extras).

Comment: @wolfram77: Note that this answer gives you the *static* instruction count.  It counts every instruction once, whether it's inside a tight loop or whether it's in error-handling code that never executes at all in normal operation.  More often you want the *dynamic* instruction count, e.g. with `sde64 --mix` [How to characterize a workload by obtaining the instruction type breakdown?](//stackoverflow.com/q/58243626) and [How do I determine the number of x86 machine instructions executed in a C program?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54355631)

Comment: That looks very promising. The `sde-mix-out.txt` on `ls` is listing a bunch of opcode types, and their counts, and there are several of those blocks. While doing that on `ls` of a directory, it seems all these counts match. When i do a diff, the only changes i see are most likely because of thread id and memory addresses changing. Thanks, i will look into it further, in order to understand the output.

Comment: Maybe it would only be possible to do static instruction usage statistics for another architecture, like Atmel AVR, or maybe run a few example programs on a simulator.