Quantifying data transfer instructions
What proportion of instructions (on average) in real-world programs is devoted to data transfer, such as the mov x86 instruction or load and store in other ISAs?

If you want to count instructions generated, you can use the shell command line I wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216890/can-apache-web-server-make-use-of-cpu-avx-instructions/75225479#75225479 Of course this doesn't disambiguate between register-register and register-memory moves. It also doesn't find operations with memory operands but it should be easy to change the grep to find [address] arguments. For instructions executed, you are probably better off using perf to look for memory bandwidth compared to instructions executed

This sounds like a subject for a scientific paper.

@Homer512 — Thank you!  That's one approach.

@LHLaurini I have been looking for one, but have not found one yet. I find it hard to believe that this research has never been done.

Related is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326190/which-processor-instructions-are-used-most-commonly?rq=3 which cites https://www.strchr.com/x86_machine_code_statistics, whose comments also cite https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/727110/citations?tabFilter=papers#citations

Real world programs written in assembly or in any language?

The slide set prepared by my former professor says that for SPECint92 on x86, 22% of instructions are pure loads, whereas 12% are pure stores.  Additionally, 4% are register to register moves.  I'm sure you'l find more details if you look into the RISC papers.  The RISC people did a lot of studies of this kind to determine what instructions to best spend their transistor budget on.

Dynamic
In order to find out how many times a certain instruction (like mov) runs, we would have to write a tracer1. To me this seems like a lot of work for not much of a result. Consider how easy it is to replace push/pop by a mov into/from stack memory and accompanied by adjusting the stackpointer of course. We'd have to trace more than just the mov instruction to obtain a meaningful metric about 'data transport'.
1 For my research on
The probability of selected EFLAGS bits I had to write such a program, and so I know it is not a trivial task.
Static
So, we could just start counting the number of times we have written the mov mnemonic in the program. That's easy enough to do but here also that does not tell us the whole story. There are a lot more instructions that deal with 'data transport'. In the example program that I have analysed, I found all the following (alphabetically): lodsb, lodsd, lodsw, lss, movsd, movsx, movsw, movzx, popa, popad, popf, pop, pusha, pushad, pushf, push, rep movsb, rep movsw, rep stosb, rep stosd, rep stosw, stosb, stosd, stosw, and xchg.
At the top of the ranking and out of a total of 2908 instructions there are 696 mov's. This is 23.93%. Adding all the other mnemonics I mentioned before, brings the total for 'data transport' up to 1145, which is 39,37%.
The second place is for the call instruction that individually ranks at 9,83%, but when considered part of the 'control flow' group we climb to 1032 instructions, which is 35,49%.
The example program is an IDE setup for Assembly and BASIC. It's a binary of 10496 bytes originating from a source of 83042 characters. It counts 3735 lines and contains 2908 instructions.
This is the sorted list of mnemonics:
mov       696
call      286
cmp       243
ret       116
pop       112
push      102
inc       093
jmps      087
je        078
add       071
int       067
dec       063
jne       062
sub       061
xor       055
jc        047
xchg      045
test      039
jb        036
jz        035
jnz       034
lodsb     029
jnb       029
loop      024
jmp       024
stosw     022
jcxz      017
stosb     015
rep movsb 015
pusha     015
popa      015
ja        015
pushad    014
popad     014
jnc       014
and       014
shr       013
js        013
lea       012
jbe       012
lodsw     010
stosd     009
jae       009
jecxz     008
stc       007
rep stosw 007
movzx     006
std       005
shl       005
neg       005
mul       005
jns       005
cld       005
lodsd     004
jna       004
div       004
cmc       004
pushf     003
popf      003
or        003
jl        003
scasb     002
sbb       002
rep stosb 002
rep movsw 002
jo        002
iret      002
imul      002
clc       002
cdq       002
cbw       002
bt        002
btr       002
aad       002
xadd      001
setnc     001
rep stosd 001
movsw     001
movsx     001
movsd     001
lss       001
jng       001
jg        001
jge       001
das       001
cwd       001
adc       001
aam       001

I compared with a much bigger program that additionally relies on FPU and SSE instructions, and that engages in a lot more diverse activities.
program   10k   60k  (x 6.0)
          ---  ----
mov       696  3222  (x 4.6)
call      286  1906  (x 6.7)
cmp       243  1283  (x 5.3)
ret       116   653  (x 5.6)

I couldn't run all the tests and for sure didn't test enough files, but already seeing that the mnemonics top 4 remained the same tempts me to this very early conclusion:
'data transport' (39%) and 'control flow' (35%) are almost equally important and they don't leave too much for the others (25%).
[EDIT]
From the OP's comment:

We should also note that arithmetic and logical operations with memory operands involve data transfer, and that call and ret should be added along with push and pop. To focus on transfers involving memory, we should exclude register-register mov instructions.

I don't believe this is what "instructions ... devoted to data transfer" means. The original question had the focus on the programmer's point of view (the desire to transfer data), where your comment approaches this from the processor's point of view (the need to transfer data).
Anyway, this too is an interesting topic to research. Using the same example program, I have located all the instructions that in one way or another have to address main memory (which could be cached).
This is the sorted list of mnemonics:
          ALL  MEM
          ---  ---
mov       696  256
call      286  286
cmp       243   96
ret       116  116
pop       112  112
push      102  102
inc        93   13
jmps       87    0
je         78    0
add        71    7
int        67   67
dec        63    7
jne        62    0
sub        61   15
xor        55    3
jc         47    0
xchg       45    5
test       39    2
jb         36    0
jz         35    0
jnz        34    0
lodsb      29   29
jnb        29    0
loop       24    0
jmp        24    0
stosw      22   22
jcxz       17    0
stosb      15   15
rep movsb  15   15
pusha      15   15
popa       15   15
ja         15    0
pushad     14   14
popad      14   14
jnc        14    0
and        14    0
shr        13    0
js         13    0
lea        12    0
jbe        12    0
lodsw      10   10
stosd       9    9
jae         9    0
jecxz       8    0
stc         7    0
rep stosw   7    7
movzx       6    5
std         5    0
shl         5    0
neg         5    1
mul         5    1
jns         5    0
cld         5    0
lodsd       4    4
jna         4    0
div         4    0
cmc         4    0
pushf       3    3
popf        3    3
or          3    1
jl          3    0
scasb       2    2
sbb         2    0
rep stosb   2    2
rep movsw   2    2
jo          2    0
iret        2    2
imul        2    0
clc         2    0
cdq         2    0
cbw         2    0
bt          2    2
btr         2    2
aad         2    0
xadd        1    1
setnc       1    1
rep stosd   1    1
movsw       1    1
movsx       1    1
movsd       1    1
lss         1    1
jng         1    0
jg          1    0
jge         1    0
das         1    0
cwd         1    0
adc         1    0
aam         1    0
         ---- ----
         2908 1289

In this case the results show that 44.33% (1289/2908) of the instructions involve transferring memory.

Thank you!  We should also note that arithmetic and logical operations with memory operands involve data transfer, and that call and ret should be added along with push and pop.  To focus on transfers involving memory, we should exclude register-register mov instructions.  Anyway, the information you posted is very helpful.

@AmittaiAviram I have added my results for the new approach you mentioned in your comment. Did you consider instruction fetch? The processor is transferring memory for 100% of these instructions. The instruction cache will have to get loaded sometime.

A general-purpose production-quality tracer for x86 already exists: Intel's PIN library which SDE (software development emulator) is built on.  You can run a binary under SDE with options to have it record a count of instruction by mnemonic.  See How to characterize a workload by obtaining the instruction type breakdown? - sde64 -mix -- ./a.out should do the trick.  another question shows an example of the output.

Or if you want to write your own code to categorize and count instructions, you could write a "PIN tool", e.g. if you want to count only instructions with memory operands, so you would count mov eax, [rdi] but not mov eax, edi.  Your code would check stuff about each instruction as PIN decodes it and runs your function on its data structure holding the decoded instruction.  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.html  (@AmittaiAviram)
